# Setter не работает

Tags: android, setter

Я пытаюсь передать объект EventDay в вызывающуюся Activity через сеттер из фрагмента. 
У меня есть рабочий код для String'a другого фрагмента, который хорошо отрабатывает. 
Не могу определить в чём проблема. Прилагаю скрины реализации
[image: Фрагмент вызова сеттера]

[image: Активити, и созданный сеттер]

Comment: Да не, все работает.

Comment: размещайте код в виде отформатированного текста, а не скриншотами. И вы не можете создавать пользовательские экземпляры системных компонентов жизненного цикла (как активити) и потом ожидать, что они будут работать (они не будут работать). Есть официальные решения по коммуникации активити- фрагмент, почему вы не используете их, а придумываете подобные недоразумения?

Comment: Использую такую конструкцию, потому что тип, который я передаю не совпадает с любым из типа putExtra()

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov а что такое EventDay, обычный класс?

Comment: [официальное решение](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating), [больше вариантов коммуникации](https://hackernoon.com/8-ways-to-communicate-between-fragment-and-activity-in-android-apps-235b60005d04)

Comment: Да, это класс из подключенной мной библиотеки работы с календарём. Можно закрывать вопрос, я нашёл альтернативный способ передачи. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если вы нашли решение, опубликуйте его, как ответ (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос") - это поможет другим пользователям быстрее решить аналогичную проблему

Answer (score 1):

В комментарии, приложенном pavloff указана невозможность создания ещё одного экземпляра активити. Проблема была решена путём расчленения переменной Eventday eventDay на 3 переменных типа int (Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.YEAR) и передачей их через стандартный intent при вызове активити из фрагмента.